# How can I display regex groups() function in dir(re)?

Tags: python

I'm still new to all this and as I'm learning I tend to spend a lot of time in the terminal with dir(). However I have tried 100x ways to get it to display the groups() function or anything similar for regex.

There's a whole list of methods and attributes for Match Objects and I don't know how to print the directory of these methods and attributes on my screen.

I'm following a course where you learn as you program basically, as a newbie. I like to follow the tutorial and program as it goes and then I try to program it again from memory and I use dir() and help() to spark my memory and get me going. But I don't really know much about objects and how to display general methods that can be used on objects.

Thanks for the help, I should have asked this question hours ago instead of repeatedly going through the rabbit hole of dir() and trying to figure out inspect() too. If I can just trace my way to a list of the methods, specifically groups() I'll be happy.

This is all that shows up for me.

```
>>> import re
>>> dir(re)
['DEBUG', 'DOTALL', 'I', 'IGNORECASE', 'L', 'LOCALE', 'M', 'MULTILINE', 'S', 
'Scanner', 'T', 'TEMPLATE', 'U', 'UNICODE', 'VERBOSE', 'X', '_MAXCACHE', 
'__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 
'__version__', '_alphanum', '_cache', '_cache_repl', '_compile', 
'_compile_repl', '_expand', '_locale', '_pattern_type', '_pickle', '_subx', 
'compile', 'copy_reg', 'error', 'escape', 'findall', 'finditer', 'match', 
'purge', 'search', 'split', 'sre_compile', 'sre_parse', 'sub', 'subn', 
'sys', 'template']

>>> dir(re.Match)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Match'
```

Comment: `dir()` will display attributes and methods. The `.groups()` method is only available on a (succesfull) regex result; certainly not on the `re` module itself (which you seem to be talking about here).

Comment: Please show us some code what you're trying to do: that may be a lot clearer than four paragraphs of plain text.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please reduce all text to the bare minimum of what code you are running, what you expected, and what you got. See [MCVE] and [ask] for a reference.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. It's more of a general case than specific code. Like I said, I'm a complete noob and this course covers stuff as it goes, not a general blanket of knowledge like maybe some general courses do. I can't provide code because it's more of a completely general thing I'm looking for. If I use regex and I assign it to a variable and I forget that they're in groups, how to I use the terminal window to remember to use the . groups function. Just like when I'm using netfilterqueue and I'm like crap, I'm forgetting something and I do dir and I'm like oh yeah .accept()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.7, match objects are instances of `re.Match`, and you can use `dir` to check its attributes and methods:

```
>>> import re
>>> dir(re.Match)
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', 
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', 
'__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
'end', 'endpos', 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'lastgroup', 
'lastindex', 'pos', 're', 'regs', 'span', 'start', 'string']
```

And then get more information:

```
>>> help(re.Match.group)
group(...)
    group([group1, ...]) -> str or tuple.
    Return subgroup(s) of the match by indices or names.
    For 0 returns the entire match.
```

The `Match` definition was added to `re` in version 3.7. See [bpo30397](https://bugs.python.org/issue30397).

Instead of using `re.Match`, you can create an actual match object and use `dir` on that.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match('x', 'x')
>>> dir(m)
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dir__',
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', 
'__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
'end', 'endpos', 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'lastgroup', 
'lastindex', 'pos', 're', 'regs', 'span', 'start', 'string']
>>> help(m.group)
... etc.
```

You can see `group` and `groups` both included in the list.

Comment: So it sounds like you have to actually make a match object? See I learned yesterday that you could do .replace on a string variable, but I was able to get there from dir(/__builtins__) and then dir(str). There's nothing like that in this case? I guess there's so many functions and they return many different types of objects and I'm trying to figure out a surefire method. But this is a big help and I will definitely start here thank you!

Comment: `str` is the type of a string. The type of a match is `re.Match`. You can call `dir` on that if you find it more convenient.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Only it's telling me that the re module does not have an attribute Match. I'll have to investigate why that it. There's a match function but no Match. I guess this is the source of my confusion and why I couldn't find this.

Comment: I think you might have a typo with `Match` (capitalised). `match` is lowercase and has become another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54207826/how-do-i-access-classes-and-get-a-dir-of-available-actions). If it's not a typo, can you please clarify if this is a version issue or something else?

Comment: @roganjosh It's not a typo, but it is a version issue. In Python 3.7.2 `re.Match` is the type of object returned by `re.match`. In Python 2.7.15 there is no such type as `re.Match`.